# Unable To Save Java Object To XML File

Tags: java, xml

I want to save my Object Mall into XML, however it doesn't seem to save when I open the XML file. Is it because there are too many objects within the Mall class to be saved therefore it can't be saved?

Below are my codes :

Mall Class

```
   public class Mall implements ActionExecute,Serializable {

    private static Mall singleton = null;
    private  ArrayList<Store> storeList = new ArrayList ();
    private  ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList ();
    public static Mall instance()
    {
        if(singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new Mall();

        }
       return singleton;
    }

  public void createStore(String factory,String storeType,String storeName)
      {

          AbstractFactory Factory  = FactoryProducer.getFactory(factory);

          if(factory.equals("store"))
          {
          Store newstore = Factory.getStore(storeType,storeName);
          storeList.add(newstore);
          }
             }
```

SaveFile Class

```
public class saveFile {
 public static void write(Mall f) throws Exception{
     try (XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(
                                  new BufferedOutputStream(
                                    new FileOutputStream("designpattern.xml")))) {
         encoder.writeObject(f);
     }
}
}
```

XML file Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_25" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
<object class="designpattern.Mall"/>
</java>
```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: I have seen sample on internet for XML file saving, there is some property and value will be saved in. and my XML file has only Object class name. is it that too many arraylist object cant be save? 
P/S : i didnt show my savefile Method because there is too many

Comment: I would use [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html)

Comment: Don't you need an Encoder that knows, for example, what tags to use in your XML representation?